# show Series Name as Legend when only one Series

Tags: c#, powerpoint, netoffice

If I have a graph with (say) two Series, and the legends showing the series names, if I hide one of the series:

```
NetOffice.PowerPointApi.Series sr = (NetOffice.PowerPointApi.Series)xob2.Chart.SeriesCollection(1);
sr.IsFiltered = true;
```

the legend changes from showing the expected remaining series name to show all of the series `XValues` - which isn't want we want, would like to retain just the one series name. Am I missing something obvious?

Worst case we can set the `hasLegend` to false and put a textbox there.

(note for various reasons we don't want to use the Excel workbooks, so would like to do this purely using the `NetOffice.PowerPointApi` capabilities)